# R Regex: removing only the immediate following character after >

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have the following string in R:

```
string1 = "A((..A>B)A"
```

I would like to remove all punctation, and the letter immediately after `>`, i.e. `>B`

Here is the output I desire:

```
output = "AAA"
```

I tried using `gsub()` as follows:

```
output = gsub("[[:punct:]]","", string1)
```

But this gives `AABA`, which keeps the immediately following character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> remove all ***punctation***, and the ***letter*** immediately after `>`

Punctuation is matched with `[[:punct:]]` and a letter can be matched with `[[:alpha:]]`, thus, you may use a TRE regex with `gsub`:

```
string1 = "A((..A>B)A"
gsub(">[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]", "", string1)
# => [1] "AAA"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/yW731w)

Note that `>` is also a char matched with `[[:punct:]]`, thus, you do not need any lookarounds here, just remove it with a letter after it.

**Pattern details**:

- `>[[:alpha:]]` - a `>` and any letter
- `|` - or
- `[[:punct:]]` - a punctuation or symbol.

Answer (score 7):

This would work using your work plus a leading lookbehind first to look for what comes after the  `>` character.

```
gsub('(?<=>).|[[:punct:]]', '', "A((..A>B)A", perl=TRUE)
## [1] "AAA"
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly less complex regex without the use of perl seems to work for this example as well:

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]|>(.)", "", "A((..A>B)A")
[1] "AAA"
```